# Forensic birthday paradox: we have $i$ distinct birthdays, how many people were counted?

Tags: statistics

Say I need to count the number of needles in a haystack I'm building. A bunch of people are picking up every piece of hay and needles they can find and putting them in a pile; as they do so I log when they're putting what where. The idea is that it's okay to get *some* needles in my haystack, but if there are too many that's a problem and the whole haystack is unfit for purpose.

At the end of the day I could just go through my log and do the needle counting after the fact. This works, but it's slow, and by the time I've run the numbers it's too late, the non compliant haystack has been made and we've got a mess in our hands. It'd be better to have some sort of live tally of needles being added so that we can stop adding needles to our haystack immediately.

Unfortunately this is somewhat challenging because the faster tally system has an issue. Say $i$ is the current tally of needles for this minute; it starts at $i := 0$. If somebody finds a needle all they can do is say $i := 1$. If another person finds a needle in the same minute, it takes too long to retrieve the current value of $i$ in order to do $i := i +1$ or in order to do any sort of decision based on the current value of $i$. At the same time, we want to measure when the actual amount of needles per minute $\hat i$ suddenly becomes very high.

An ameliorative approach suggested by Google is to have $k$ distinct tallies $i_n$, then every time you want to tally, you do $i_n := 1$ for a random choice of $n \in [1,k]$.

Say that in a minute we add $\hat i$ needles to a haystack. By the birthday paradox, if at the end of the minute you have $I = \sum i_n \ll k$ tallies per minute, you can say that $E(\hat i) \simeq I$. In general if I had a limit $\bar i$ of needles per minute beyond which I'm in trouble, and all I have to do is calculate $p(\hat i < \bar i | I = x)$.

I just noticed that Wikipedia has [a "direct" formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#The_generalized_birthday_problem) for determining a value of $k$ that makes collisions less than $p$ likely for all $I < \bar i $, for example: $$ k > \left\lceil \sqrt{\frac{2\bar{i}}{-\log(1-p)}} \right\rceil $$ ...so if I have some thresholds of acceptability I could just use that to determine a lower bound on the number of buckets.

That said the minute ends and I have $I < k$ tallies for my $k$ buckets. What's $E(\hat i)$? What statistical distribution am I looking at?

Comment: This isn't clear to me. What exactly are these tallies, who's tallying what, what does it mean to have a certain number of tallies per minute at the end of a minute, ...? The narrative style of the question is nice, but at some point you also need to state more formally what you have and what you want.

Comment: @joriki if I said a bunch of web workers talking to graphite, would it help? I'm not quite sure.

Comment: I understand that even less than I understand the question. Just to point out one specific problem among many: You start talking about "buckets" in the penultimate paragraph, but you never introduced them. My suggestion would be to lay out (in addition to the current narrative development, not necessarily replacing it) the entire problem in a more formal style, from start to finish, specifying what you have, introducing every element that you use, and stating what you want to achieve.